# Magento 2: Display product inventory on frontend based on store select

Tags: magento2, multistore, inventory, multi-source-inventory

[image]

I want to display product inventory based on store select on frontend.(product should be updated on store select)

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Magento doesn't support different stock levels on different Stores, only on different Websites (anndonly when you use MCI)

Answer (score 0):

Can you please check below link that will help you ?
https://docs.magento.com/user-guide/configuration/catalog/inventory.html

[image]